# Graph the function with an absolute minimum at (-2,-12), a local maximum at (0,3), a local minimum at (2,-1), and an absolute maximum at (4,9)?

Tags: calculus

I used elimination to gather the function: $$\frac{11}{19}x^3 - \frac{19}{8}x^2 + 3$$

I thought I was on the right track until I noticed that (2,-1) wasn't on the local minimum.  It almost slipped passed me.

But what is going on, where did I go wrong?

[image: graph]

Answer (score 3):

The question says to only graph it, not to find the expression of such a function. I would just graph a function that has these requirements, without forcing it to be of any particular type (trig, polynomial, ...).

By the way, if the function is considered on $\mathbb{R}$, then no polynomial can satisfy those requirements, since polynomials have no absolute maximum/minimum on $\mathbb{R}$ (unless it's a constant).

Comment: Wow I went a little off base.  Does this just mean to draw it?

Comment: I'd say 'graph' is pretty much a synonym of 'sketch', 'draw'. ;-)